# Get word between two sets of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that takes any word between these two sets of characters:
**`3D`** and **`&sa`**

*examples*:

**3D**`Evb31p5vFs4_`**&sa**  : the output : `Evb31p5vFs4_`

**3D**`_Ve8_LBztG50_`**&sa**  : the output : `_Ve8_LBztG50_`

I have used the expression: `/\w[3D][A-Za-z0-9_-].*sa/g`
So the next step is to skip the "3D" and "&sa"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the regular expressions you've tried so far?

Comment: this is the main string that im tring to get the word form: (https://www.google.com/url?q=%3Fv%3DEvb31p5vFs4&sa=U&ved=0CAUQhUKEwjM7c7A) ... i have used the expression: (/\w[3D][A-Za-z0-9_-].*sa/g) so the next step is to skip the "3D" and "&sa"

Comment: @Makaveli included your tried regex in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**  with regex `/3D(.*)&sa/`

```js
var a='3DEvb31p5vFs4_&sa';
var b='3D_Ve8_LBztG50_&sa' ;

document.write(a.match(/3D(.*)&sa/)[1] +'<br>');
document.write(b.match(/3D(.*)&sa/)[1]);
```

**Explanation:**

```
3D(.*)&sa
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FWSk4Pco936iBpct)

Comment: @Makaveli : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
3D(?s)(.*)&sa
```

Explaination:

```
3D matches the characters 3D literally (case sensitive)
(?s) Match the remainder of the pattern with the following options:
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
1st Capturing group (.*)
.* matches any character
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
&sa matches the characters &sa literally (case sensitive)
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```